# Avoid putting the same handler as a props

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to avoid passing the same handler as a prop to children component every time ?

I create a `Popup` component and i want it to update the sate before closing

```
    closePoPup = (e) => {

        console.log('closePoPup');

        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            renderProgramePoPup: false,
            renderTreeListPoPup: false,
        })
    } 

    .....

    <Popup title="..." classes="..." closePoPup={this.closePoPup}>
        <Foo ... />
    </Popup
```

But i have to put the prop `closePoPup={this.closePoPup}` in every component like bellow :

```
class ProjectForm extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            renderProgramePoPup: false,
            renderTreeListPoPup: false,
        });
    }
    ....
    closePoPup = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            renderProgramePoPup: false,
            renderTreeListPoPup: false,
        })
    }
    ....
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    ...
                    {(this.state.renderProgramePoPup ?
                        <Popup title="..." classes="..."
                            closePoPup={this.closePoPup}>
                            <SimplePopUp ... />
                        </Popup> : null
                    )}

                    {(this.state.renderTreeListPoPup ?
                        <Popup title="..." classes="..."
                            closePoPup={this.closePoPup}>
                            <TreeList ... />
                        </Popup> : null
                    )}
                </div>   
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a wrapper:

```
render() {
  const PopupWithCloseProp = props => <Popup closePoPup={this.closePoPup} {...props} />;
  return (
    <div>
      <PopupWithCloseProp someProp />
      <PopupWithCloseProp someDiffProp />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or a generic factory if you have different types of components needing `closePoPup`:

```
const createComponentWithCloseProp = Component => props => (
  <Component closePoPup={this.closePoPup} {...props} />
);

const PopupWithCloseProp = createComponentWithCloseProp(Popup);
```

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution is to create a list or object `this.state.renderPopUp`. Then you can `map()` over the list (or `Object.keys()`) to create a list of `Popup`s. You can extend this idea even further by including data for each `Popup` in the list.